# How can I fix the 'Failed to execute setLocalDescription' error in WebRTC using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to make a video calling app. Where i want to use webrtc. But when i am implementing this i got an error.

My js code is:

```
let localStream;
let remoteStream;
let peerConnection;

// const servers = {
//     iceServers: [
//         {
//             urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
//         }
//     ]
// }

var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

roomId = urlParams.get("room");
name = urlParams.get("name");
socket.emit("join-channel", { room: roomId });
socket.on("room-message", function (message) {
    handleMessage(message, roomId);
});

let init = async () => {

    socket.on("MemberJoined", (data) => {
        handleUserJoined(roomId);
    });

    localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    document.getElementById("vid-1").srcObject = localStream;
}

let handleUserJoined = async (roomId) => {
    console.log('A new user joined the room: ', roomId);
    createOffer(roomId);
}

let handleMessage = async (message, roomId) => {
    message = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message).text);

    if (message.type === "offer"){
        createAnswer(roomId, message.offer);
    }

    if (message.type === "answer"){
        addAnswer(message.answer);
    }

    if (message.type === "candidate"){
        if (peerConnection){
            peerConnection.addIceCandidate(message.candidate);
        }
    }
}

let createPeerConnection = async (roomId) => {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({'iceServers': [{'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]});

    remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    document.getElementById("vid-2").srcObject = remoteStream;

    if (!localStream) {
        localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
        document.getElementById("vid-1").srcObject = localStream;
    }
    
    localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    })

    peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            remoteStream.addTrack(track);
        })
    }

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = async (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            socket.emit('room-message', { room: roomId, message: { text: JSON.stringify({ "type": 'candidate', "candidate": event.candidate }) } })
        }
    }
}

let createOffer = async (roomId) => {

    await createPeerConnection(roomId);

    let offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer)

    socket.emit('room-message', { room: roomId, message: { text: JSON.stringify({ "type": 'offer', "offer": offer }) } })
}

let createAnswer = async (roomId, offer) => {
    await createPeerConnection(roomId);

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer); // Set remote description first

    let answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

    socket.emit('room-message', { room: roomId, message: { text: JSON.stringify({ "type": "answer", "answer": answer }) } });
};


let addAnswer = async (answer) => {
    if (!peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription){
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }
}

init();
```

my error is:

main.js:104 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

In backend i used flask socketio. Socket communication is fine. But problem in peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);.